# Magento 2: How to track list of event generated in checkout order placed?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, place-order

How to get **list of all events are executed where magento place order in checkout page**?
Get the list of all events step by steps.
Any tools we can observe which event fire first and which events are used at that steps?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it.

You need to create a module and a plugin for that.

In `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` you need the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface">
        <plugin name="list_dispatched_event" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ListDispatchedEvents" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in your `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/ListDispatchedEvents.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class ListDispatchedEvents
{
    public function beforeDispatch($subject, $eventName, array $data = [])
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($eventName);
    }

}
```

Then I suggest you disable that module until you reach the page where you can click the Place Order button. Re enable module, click the button, disable the module once the the page has redirected you to the success page and check the `var/log/test.log` file.

Answer (score 2):

All events go through `Magento\Framework\Event\Manager::dispatch`.
you can add a logger inside that method or build a `before` plugin to log the `$eventName` variable passed to the method. Then go through the checkout process and see what's logged.

Comment: Haha exactly what I just wrote ^^

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Not exactly, but pretty close. I might think you are copying my answers :D

Comment: I time travel in the future to steal your answers, didn't I tell you ?

Comment: Actually I answered 4 minutes faster. So I guess I traveled in the past to post before you :)

Comment: Dammit you're right, I guess you tricked me, you're the one stealing my answers ^^